# Why do you open a gulp src pipe when you use gulp-watch?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm learning Gulp, and I have seen some examples that I don't quite understand.

This example is from the gulp-watch page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

```
gulp.task('callback', function (cb) {
    watch('css/**/*.css', function () { < we called watch here
        gulp.src('css/**/*.css') < -- why do I need to use .src here (is there a reason that I didn't accept the vinyl parameter and use it?)
            .pipe(watch('css/**/*.css'))<-- why do we call watch again here?
            .on('end', cb);
    });
```

Is that a recursive call to watch()? And why do ew call gulp.src again, if the callback function can have a parameter that has the vinyl file?